# Likelihood of a censored data vs. likelihood based on IPCW weights

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

I was wondering if there is a relation between the classical form of the likelihood when we have censored observation : i.e

Let's define $T_i = \inf(X_i,C_i)$ and $\delta_i = \mathbb{1}_{X_i \leq C_i} $. The likelihood is equal to :
$$L(θ) = \prod_{i=1}^n (f_θ(T_i)S_C(T_i))^{\delta_i}
(f_C(T_i)S_θ(T_i))^{1−\delta_i} $$

Now, with IPCW weights (defined in a simple form as: $W_{i,n}=\frac{\delta_i}{nS_C(Y_i)}$)
We can define another likelihood estimator as :
$$ \log(\hat{L}(\theta)) = \sum_{i=1}^n W_{i,n} \log(f_\theta(X_i)) $$

For example :
I've found that Satten & Datta (2001) worked on some statistical propities of the Kapan-Meier estimator that can be expressed in an additif form with IPCW weighted as :
$$ S_{KM}(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n W_{i,n} \mathbb{1}_{Y_i>t}$$

Thank you,